# how to clean the implicit declaration of function in C?

Tags: c, function

I have a question regarding to the function declaration:

I declared a function in b.c

```
//b.c
void getNumber();

//common header
common.h
```

In a.c I use it like this:
//a.c

```
#include "common.h"
void getInfo()
{
   getNumber();
}
```

but it complain the getNumber is implicit declaration of function, what is the reason?

Comment: You should put the declaration into `common.h`, not into `b.c`.

Comment: `void foo()` is not a prototype, you should use `void foo(void)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following line to `common.h`

```
void getNumber();
```

the b.c file should contain the function definition in this way

```
void getNumber() {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare or define your function first before using it.

If your declaration `void getNumber();` was read by the compiler after its first use (`void getInfo()`), you would get the warning `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getNumber’`.  This happened because the compiler, when first encountering `getNumber` in `void getInfo()` had to guess its return type - hence the warning.  I think this is what you are doing even though your example code does not show it that way.

If your `void getNumber();` was read by the compiler first, no warning would occur.

Putting your function declaration in a header file like is a good idea.  Be sure to `include "common.h"` first before your `getInfo()`.